# Python Tkinter: Sending realtime data to another class/window

Tags: python, class, tkinter

This is just a small sample of a project's larger problem. There are 2 classes. Both are Tkinter windows. SecondClass sends information to the FirstClass's Tkinter label. The expected behavior is to see the label in the FirstClass reflect the changing values sent from the for-loop of the SecondClass as they happen. Just to prove that the loop is functioning correctly, the print statement prints the values to the terminal.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
class FirstClass:
    #This is the receiving windo
    root.geometry("300x300")
    root.title("First Window")
    #We expect the label text to change with each loop
    label = Label(root, text="The original message")
    label.pack()


class SecondClass:
    #Create the transmitting window
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.geometry("300x300")
    toplevel.title("Second Window")
    # Create instance of FirstClass
    firstclass = FirstClass
    for counter in range(3):
        #Send the loop count to First Window
        # FirstClass.label.config(text='Count is '+str(counter))
        firstclass.label.config(text='Count is '+str(counter))
        print(str(counter))
        time.sleep(1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is not the solution but it seems the problem is "sequence". That is the loop is being called before the windows are created. I believe a function needs to be called AFTER the windows are instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `instance` of `FirstClass` and pass it in `SecondClass` ,You can use `after()` to run a function after a certain time which will help to update.
The `after()` method calls the `callback` function once after a delay milliseconds (ms) within Tkinter’s main loop.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class FirstClass:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("300x300")
        self.root.title("First Window")
        self.label = Label(self.root, text="The original message")
        self.label.pack()

    def update_label(self, text):
        self.label.config(text=text)

class SecondClass:
    def __init__(self, root, first_class):
        self.root = root
        self.first_class = first_class
        self.toplevel = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.toplevel.geometry("300x300")
        self.toplevel.title("Second Window")
        self.counter = 0
         
        self.update_label()
    
    def update_label(self):
        #update_label method of FirstClass to update the label text.
        self.first_class.update_label('Count is ' + str(self.counter))
        print(str(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter < 10:
            # set delay in ms to update the first_window
            self.root.after(1000, self.update_label)

root = Tk()
first_class = FirstClass(root)
# created an instance of FirstClass and pass it to SecondClass as a parameter. 
second_class = SecondClass(root, first_class)
root.mainloop()
```

The `update_label` method is called repeatedly using the `after` method of the `root` window, which will update in real-time.
Here is tut for `after()` https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/

Comment: Thank you very much. I discovered the window.update() method and now learned about the after() method. Your time is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows.update() could be another solution. In this example, we created a function outside the two class files and called the function from a button in the SecondClass to update the label widget of the FirstClass. This the function:

```
def sendinfo():
# Create instance of FirstClass
firstclass = FirstClass
for counter in range(5):
    #Send the loop count to First Window
    # FirstClass.label.config(text='Count is '+str(counter))
    firstclass.label.config(text='Count is '+str(counter))
    root.update()
    print(str(counter))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The button in the SecondClass that calls the function is:

```
button = Button(toplevel, text='Send info', command=sendinfo)
```